# Creating A Default Scratch Org in Visual Studio Code for Salesforce.. Getting Error with Exit Code 1

Tags: error, vs-code

I am new to Salesforce Development. I just installed Visual Studio Code.  I did successfully auhorize my Dev Org. But I am having issues when creating a Default Scratch Org. THe following the error message I am receiving.  Please advise!!

[image]

Comment: Have you enabled Dev Hub in your Org?

Answer (score 0):

Either you have not enabled [Dev Hub](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_enable_devhub.htm), or you did not create the [Permission Set](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_add_users.htm) you need. Make sure you have enabled Dev Hub in Setup, and make sure you created a Permission Set and assigned it to your user--simply being a System Administrator is not sufficient to use Dev Hub features.

Comment: Thanks!!  What permission do I need to assign as Permission set for the user